# How can I handle binary data in Frege?

Tags: frege

I'm new to Frege, although I know both Java and Haskell.

I'm porting some Haskell code that uses `ByteString`, and I'm trying to figure out what to use in Frege.  I assume I would want to use something whose underlying Java representation is `byte[]`, but I'm not sure how Frege wraps that.

In particular, I looked through `PreludeArrays.fr`, and I noticed that there's an instance of `PrimitiveArrayElement` for every primitive Java type *except* `byte`.

I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing.  How do I go about dealing with binary data in Frege?  Are there any examples of how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There actually is such an instance. It just can't be in `PreludeArrays` for technical reasons. Rather it lives in `frege.java.Lang`, where `Byte` and `Short` are introduced.

Even if there were none, you simply could say

```
instance PrimitiveArrayElement Byte
```

and it should work.

Regarding your question: I think it is safe to say that `JArray Byte` should be ok for any problem with any data. Another question is if it is the best   representation. For example, if those data actually are UTF8 strings, I would think that conversion into `String` would be the way to go.

Things to consider

1. `mapArray`, `foldArray` and friends  are space efficient, but strict and a bit slow, because they use the `ST` monad.
2. Conversely, `map` and `fold` are reasonably fast, but of course squander lots of memory.

An approach I have used in `frege.data.Hashmap` was to identify very basic array operations and implement them in Java (one can do this in-line, even), and write the rest of the program in terms of those.

You may want to look at the source code to get an idea of how to do this.